# Jquery request always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the dark sky forecast api https://developer.forecast.io/  to retrieve json object via jquery get request.the required url parameters format is (api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE") while the valid format with the parameters is:
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/02a90a53f4705dc5e5b54f8cda15d805/9.055169,7.49115
inputting this url  in your browser will show you a json object.

First thing i tried was a jquery get request :

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET'
     , data: ''
     , url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/02a90a53f4705dc5e5b54f8cda15d805/9.055169,7.49115"
     , success: function (data) {
         alert("works");

     }
     , datatype: 'json'


     , error: function (err) {
         alert("Could not get forecast");
     }

 });
```

this is not succesful- it triggers the error function. i try again using a post request it doesnt work either.please help

Comment: Sorry, "doesn't work" doesn't provide any information needed to help you.

Comment: PROTIP: Don't include your *real* API key in your question.

Comment: You *cannot* directly contact their API with JavaScript.  This is because of the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  Their API doesn't support CORS (or JSONP), which means they don't support cross-domain loading.  You need to use a server-side language to query this API then make an AJAX call to that.

Comment: You are hitting a security issue regarding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, from what server are you requesting the API?

You can try using a library https://github.com/iantearle/forecast.io-javascript-api

Comment: @montogeek i dont yet know php.i dont know how to use the library

Comment: @scroobius It's a JS library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple CORS issue which can be easily resolved by using `jsonp` datatype:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/02a90a53f4705dc5e5b54f8cda15d805/9.055169,7.49115",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.latitude, data.longitude);
    console.log(data.timezone);
    console.log(data.daily.summary);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log("Could not get forecast");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>Loading . . .<em>
```